# Nightwatch launch_url not picking up global value

Tags: url, nightwatch.js, launch

I have the following set up in my **globals.js** file;

```
const carReviews = 'car-reviews/'

module.exports = {
carReviews,
waitForConditionTimeout: 5000,
},
```

And this set up in my **nightwatch.conf.js** file'

```
  launch_url: 'https://www.parkers.co.uk',
```

With this in my test script;

```
.url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carReviews)
```

However, when I run the test I get the following url issue on each occasion;

**https://www.parkers.co.ukundefined/**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the globals path to your nightwatch config?

`"globals_path": "Global.js"`

Edit: I added your provided code to my setup and it worked. My assumption is that you're adding your `globals_path` to your `test_settings` object within your nightwatch config, but you should have it in the root of `module.exports`. Please post your full config if this isn't the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this in my original post, so apologies for this. In my **nightwatch.conf.js** file I have the following; `globals_path: 'config/globals.js'`

Comment: Try seeing what Nightwatch is loading as your globals:


`.url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carReviews, function() {
        console.log(browser.globals)
      })
`

It might also be where you are defining your globals_path in your nw config. Mine looks like:

`module.exports = {
  "src_folders": [
    "e2e/test-scripts"
  ],
  "page_objects_path": ["./e2e/pages"],
  "globals_path": 'globals.js',
  "output_folder": "./test/reports",
`

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for the reply!

You were right, I'd defined the globals_path within my nightwatch config.

Moving it to the root of my module.exports appears to have fixed my issues.

Thanks for your help :)